# Bernoulli-measure of infinite word.

Tags: probability-theory

The [Bernoulli measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_scheme) $\mu$ is defined on finite blocks, that is for a block

$[y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n]m:=\{x=(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}: x_m=y_1, x_{m+1}=y_2,\ldots,x_{m+n}=y_n\}$

we have
$$
\mu([y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n]m) = \prod_{j=1}^np_j,
$$
where $p_j$ is the probability of $y_j$.

I am a bit confused what the probability of an infinite word is, say, of
$$
x=(\ldots,y_1,y_1,y_1,\ldots)
$$
which has bi-infinitely many entries $y_1$.

Does this have measure zero?

Surely, one has
$$
\mu(x)=\mu\left(\bigcap_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}[y_1]_i\right)
$$

but what is the right hand side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that there is no index $j$ with $p_j = 1$. Then, because of $\bigcap_{j \in \mathbb Z} [y_1]_j \subset \bigcap_{j = -m}^m [y_1]_j$ for any $m \in \mathbb N$, we have $$\mu \left( \bigcap_{j \in \mathbb Z} [y_1]_j \right) \leq \mu \left( \bigcap_{j = -m}^m [y_1]_j \right) = p_1^{2m+1} \xrightarrow{m\to \infty} 0 .$$

Comment: Yes, in fact I was thinking of each outcome having the same probability. Thanks!

Comment: What about an arbitrary word $x$ of infinite length, does it also has measure zero? My idea would be to use $$\mu(x)\leq \mu\left(\bigcap_{-m}^m[x_{-m},\ldots,x_m]_{-m}\right)\to 0, \qquad m\to\infty.$$ In other words: **Every** infinite word has measure $0$?

Comment: The same argument works, then you have $\ldots \leq \prod_{j=-m}^m p_j \leq p_k^{2m+1}$ where $k$ is an index such that $p_k = \max_j p_j$. So yes, every infinite word has measure $0$ (under the mild assumption from my question).

Comment: Please see my last comment.

Comment: doesn't my comment answer your last comment?

Comment: It does. Just wanted to make sure that I had the correct idea.

Comment: yes you do. The idea is exactly the same